# Automatically Adjusting Indicator for Specific Timeframes

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script and looking for help with understanding how to show the right indicator information when the chart timeframe is adjusted.

My goal is to only show the "sma52Weekly" indicator data when you navigate to the weekly chart view, and only the "sma252Daily" indicator data when you navigate to the daily chart view. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated - thank you in advance!

```
study("LoremIpsum")
resolution = "W"
 
sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval='SPCFD:SPX')
spx = security(sym, resolution, close)
stock = close
 
stockDividedBySpx = stock / spx
sma52Weekly = sma(stockDividedBySpx,52)
sma252Daily = sma(stockDividedBySpx,252)
 
plot(sma52Weekly, title= 'MA(52)',color=color.blue)
plot(sma252Daily, title= 'MA(252)',color=color.red)
plot(stockDividedBySpx, title= 'stock/SPX',color=color.black)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timeframe.period` to get the current timeframe of the chart, and then plot accordingly:

```
//@version=4

study("LoremIpsum")
resolution = "W"
 
sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval='SPCFD:SPX')
spx = security(sym, resolution, close)
stock = close
 
stockDividedBySpx = stock / spx
sma52Weekly = sma(stockDividedBySpx,52)
sma252Daily = sma(stockDividedBySpx,252)
 
plot(timeframe.period == "W" ? sma52Weekly : na, title= 'MA(52)',color=color.blue)
plot(timeframe.period == "D" ? sma252Daily : na, title= 'MA(252)',color=color.red)
plot(stockDividedBySpx, title= 'stock/SPX',color=color.black)
```